# Why did organic search traffic increase at the same time paid campaigns were stopped?

Tags: google-ads

Organic increased up from 20,000 to 25,000 at the same time paid search were stopped. I think there should be no dependency between organic and paid search, but could there be any meaninful dependency between these? e.g. Bad keyword set?

[image: Organic Search Vs. Paid Search]

Comment: Correlation does not imply causation.   Just because one changed when the other did, it doesn't mean they are related.  It looks like coincidence to me.  Organic traffic will often fluctuate by 20% or more due to seasonality or ranking changes.   I doubt it has anything to do with the end of your AdWords campaigns.

Answer (score 3):

That's not really that surprising, and suggests that you have some decent organic rankings.

Imagine users are searching for a product you sell, and they see your ad listing before your organic listing; that's what they'll click first. If there's no ad shown, but your organic listing is the first relevant link, then many users will still click that.